# AsyncTask - JSON Android Studio error in doInBackground

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am learning how to create a simple register program that registers user input into MySQL database. But whenever I click the register button, my application will be forced close. Why is that?

This is my logcat:

```
    06-03 08:53:33.841    1529-1539/com.example.minzhe.sqltest E/Buffer Error﹕ Error         06-03 08:53:33.851    1529-1539/com.example.minzhe.sqltest E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
    06-03 08:53:33.851    1529-1539/com.example.minzhe.sqltest W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    06-03 08:53:33.861    1529-1539/com.example.minzhe.sqltest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing         doInBackground()
                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
                at         java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.minzhe.sqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:112)
                at com.example.minzhe.sqltest.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:70)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

This is code for Register class:

```
    package com.example.minzhe.sqltest;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        private EditText user, pass;
        private Button  mRegister;

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        //php login script

        private static final String LOGIN_URL =  "http://127.0.0.1/webservice/register.php";


        //ids
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register);

            //EditText user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            //EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

            mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
            mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new CreateUser().execute();

        }

        class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
            boolean failure = false;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                EditText user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
                String username = user.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();


                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");

                    //Posting user data to script
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                    // full json response
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                    // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                        finish();
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (file_url != null){
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            if ( pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing() ){
                pDialog.cancel();
            }
        }


    }
```

This my JSONParser code:

```
    package com.example.minzhe.sqltest;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        // function get json from url
        // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {

                // check for request method
                if(method == "POST"){
                    // request method is POST
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                }else if(method == "GET"){
                    // request method is GET
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");        
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is 112 in Register class

Comment: you are using 127.0.0.1 which is known as localhost means the self server and its always point itself so the device will  find that site on itself not on your computer

Comment: @Amsheer line 112 is Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi I am currenctly using xamp server, if 127.0.0.1 cant be used, what can i use?

Comment: you can use it but make sure that the website you are running in xampp server is opening in your device's browser or emulator

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi It is accessible when i type http://127.0.0.1/webservice/register.php

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi You can not check post url in browser. Here he is using "POST" so. It is not possible to check in browser. There is different tools to test it.

Comment: OK.. are you sure that the webservice will definitely return a json object ?

Comment: @Amsheer you are right but i just told that the website 127.0.0.1 should be accessible which is the default page of xampp server

Comment: I am not sure. But when i access  127.0.0.1/webservice/register.php i am able to register a new user. It only does not work in android studio @GopalSinghSirvi

Comment: also make sure that your script ( register.php ) is also correct. I think there was a problem in that script which is not returning anything on post request

Comment: @ElzyT'Ahzhe Android studio is just an IDE. This is not causing issue. Check your read json response code

Comment: Make sure that the control is not going here... ;)  `Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());`

Comment: Why are you initializing your Edittext in DoinBackground?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nullPointer exception in the following line

```
Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
```

Which means your json.toString() is null simply your json return from

```
//Posting user data to script
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

is null. Add some values with json then print log.

```
Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString()+"**");
```

**EDIT**

The issue is with your json response. So you need to do that any tool to check response

I suggest use [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

Comment: What do you mean by add some values with json?

Comment: I mean that your json response is null. So add some dummy string in the log then there is no crash. Like this Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString()+"**");

Comment: This is not the issue. It is just nullpointer exception this is happenening becausej  sonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            LOGIN_URL, "POST", params); this returns null.

Comment: How can i change it so that i doesnt return null?

Comment: Yes that is what i told. You post some log that is not the issue. the real issue is reading json is wrong.  Debug this method  makeHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

```
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

I think something wrong with the response / you don't get the full response. So it end up this line of code is failed, and of course the function
 `public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params)`
return jObj which is null.
Then in class `Register` you just perform some operation on that `null` value.

Then the fix should be this after performing http call in here

`JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);`,

you should checking if the return value is `null` or not:

```
if (json != null) {
 // perform something here
} else {
 // null return from JSONParser
}
```

Anyway, you shouldn't create a class that actually perform HTTP call inside JSONParser class. It's misleading.